# How to debug with anaconda after install in sublime text 3?

Tags: python, anaconda, sublime-anaconda

I have installed Anaconda using Package Manager on ST3. In looking at a Python source file I see some fancy new formatting options and the Command Palette has a variety of Anaconda commands, none of which seem to describe running a program or debugging a program. The closest is run current test, but when I try it the console shows a traceback for index out of range.

What am I missing?

Perhaps Anaconda as a Sublime plug-in doesn't support debugging?

Comment: Have you tried a Python IDE like PyCharm or PyDev? They have excellent support for both writing and debugging Python scripts.

Comment: Spyder (python IDE) is included with anaconda.  Normally this can be found in .../AnacondaX/scripts/spyder.exe

Comment: @16num -- thanks. Do you think I can run Spyder within Sublime Text? There seems to be both a stand-alone Anaconda product as well as a plug-in for ST3. I have been hoping to use Sublime for all my work in all languages rather than learning the configuration eccentricities of a new text editor for each language, but it doesn't look promising.

Comment: @WesR -- I doubt it.  At least not without a lot of work.  The Spyder display is written in qt.  I'm sure it's possible but a quick google search didn't turn anything up.  If you end up abandoning your search for making sublime work, Spyder doesn't have much of a configuration to it.  Not like eclipse or intellij.

Comment: @16num Thanks. Today's swat in this game of whack-a-mole is pdb++ with Sublime. If this doesn't work out I will try Spyder next.

Comment: Check if your project has a folder named `code`. rename it